# <a> That both links to anchor AND toggles data-toggle collapse

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, bootstrap-4

I have the following code to let the surfer move to #OntdekPlus div:

```
<div class="pakket-box-cta bg-armonea-rood m-0 p-2">
    <p class="text-center"><a href="#OntdekPlus" class="btn armonea-grijs-1">Ontdek <span class="text-uppercase">Plus</span></a></p>
</div>
```

Further down the page, I have the following link that toggles a collapse element, but it doesn't move the surfer to #OntdekPlus:

```
<a class="ontdek-card-btn w-100" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOntdekPlus" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOntdekPlus">
    <h3 class="mb-0">Ontdek <span class="text-uppercase"><strong>Plus</strong></span></h3>
</a>
```

But I need a link that does both (move to anchor AND toggle the collapse) but I can only manage to have one of the two functions working. This is what I came up with:

```
<p class="text-center"><a href="#OntdekPlus" data-target="#collapseOntdekPlus" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOntdekPlus" class="btn armonea-grijs-1">Ontdek <span class="text-uppercase">Plus</span></a></p>
```

Here is the full piece of html for the div where I want to anchor too: https://pastebin.com/3RBmXNSp

Is it possible to do both? Where in the code am I making a mistake?

Comment: I think the cleanest solution would be to hook into the events BS collapse provides, so that you scroll that element into view when it gets opened. (A custom click handler that simply sets `location.hash` might also work.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Location.hash might be a simple solution indeed.